# MS OpenidConnect : Multitenancy on a nodejs web application

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have registered an app on my tenant as multitenant app. 
using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-openidconnect-nodejs).

I am able to login with users only if the users are on my tenant. Any other tenant user, I am unable to login.

I have set validateIssuer to false too.

The error I get is

> User account 'xxx@tenantY.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/'
>   does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the
>   application 'App Id' in that tenant. The
>   account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
>   Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory
>   user account.

Not sure if there is a sample to make other tenant users to access the app. 
Role delegated permission is set to 'Sign in and read user profile' alone

Answer (score 0):

There are four steps to convert your application into an Azure AD multi-tenant app:

1. [Update your application registration to be multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant)
2. [Update your code to send requests to the /common endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common)
3. [Update your code to handle multiple issuer values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values)
4. [Understand user and admin consent and make appropriate code changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent)

Please verify if above steps are followed.